# I want to write a script from which I can use the name variable into another scene in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VisualNovelScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static string InputName;
    public GameObject InputField;

    public void StoreName()
    {
        InputName = InputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
    }

}
```

This is the script from which i want the name variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UserNameInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string InputNameShow;
    public GameObject TextDisplay;

    public void SetName()
    {
        InputNameShow = VisualNovelScript.InputName;
        TextDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hello " + InputNameShow;
    }
}
```

And this is the script from where i linked the variable from the first script and i want to show the name that the user entered, i've tried different possibilities for the past few days but none of them worked.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Assigning a value to the static variable should persist across scene unloads/loads.

Answer (score 1):

I think better is using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) for this task, also no need to refer GO and get component, you can just refer to its type directly. Your code should look like this then

```
public InputField InputField;
public void StoreName()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Username", InputField.text);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

And in your other scene use `GetString`

```
public Text TextDisplay;
public void SetName()
{
    TextDisplay.text = "Hello " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username");
}
```

Comment: For some reason the second script doesnt work, only the first one.

Comment: try to debug if PlayerPrefs are correct like `Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username"));`

Comment: It doesn't say in the console anything when i load into the second scene.

Comment: check that your method is being called

Comment: Are both of your scripts attached to game objects and the functions are called?

Comment: accept answer, if you have no other questions, please